# Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to learn microservices by creating a dummy project.
I have a config repository in git and a config server running at port 8888.It's working properly as I can see my settings as below:
[image]

Now I have two microservice projects 1) customer service and 2) customer-account-service. customer microservice is running properly while customer-account-microservice is unable to start and throwing below exception:

```
*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted*
```

bootstrap.properties configuration for customer-account-microservice is as below:

[image]

pom.xml configuration for customer-account-microservice is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer-account-microservice</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>customer-account-microservice</name>
    <description>Spring starter project for demonstrating spring feign client and circuit breaker</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-services.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-circuit-breaker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help me in fixing the above exception.

Comment: May I ask why the h2 dependency is part the the `dependencyManagement` block instead the dependencies block?

Comment: @sn42 copy paste error and after moving h2 dependency under dependencies block, code worked. Thanks alot for pointing this error.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems that your dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

has to be in `dependencies` element, not in `dependencyManagement`. Just look at [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). Or maybe you have a child artifact, in that case you must share another pom xml.

Answer (score 19):

in my case, I had a space after the "driver"

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver...
```

I deleted it and it works just fine

Comment: It really helped.

Comment: This was in my case too

Comment: Great hint ! Thank you !

An a very strange bug that shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 16):

I change it to 'compile' and it solved my problem.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue in IDEA IntellJ even after using the correct dependency in `pom.xml`. It boils down to IDE specific issue where it was not able to download `h2` dependency. It worked after restarting the IDE.

Comment: Thank you Ashish, restart resolved the issue

Comment: Sad, but true, ItelliJ is becoming more and more an Eclipse-next-gen. Right mouse on the project->maven->reload project also seems to help

Comment: I was using gradle and had the same issue with Intellij.  Restart solved the problem.  Thank you Ashish!

Comment: Thanks, reloading the project really helped!

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was caused by some trailing blank characters behind the driver classname in application.properties

This fails (dots in the code snippet below should be read as whitespace chars):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver...
```

This succeeds:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 3):

I commented spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver, that worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case I gave the gradle dependency wrong.

I should give it in dependencies {implementation}, but I gave it in dependencies {testImplementation} in build.gradle file

The below mentioned is right

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.212' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was using an outdated version of the h2 dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
```

I fixed it by removing the version tag so that the latest version is downloaded :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
In application.properties file, there are white spaces after adding configurations
You can see IDEA IntellJ like this
[image]

Should remove all the white spaces in application.properties file. Then the test cases failed issue will be solved

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have added dependencies now add **spring.datasource.platform=h2** in your application.properties

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I made:

**application-test.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

unsetting those datasource properties was only needed because I set them in the base `application.properties`. It'd be simpler just to not define them there and instead have them in the profile-specific properties, but leaving this here in case anyone else wants a quick/lazy fix

**build.gradle.kts**

```
testImplementation("com.h2database:h2")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Repleace scope test to runtime .it worked for me!.

Comment: if you do this and leave the dependencyManagement section of the pom.xml as is the case w/ the pom.xml that is submitted w/ the question, it won't work.