# Maven structure problem when adding h2 database dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

When I try to add h2database dependency to my maven pom.xml I get 151 errors and can't build.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>something</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>something else</name>
    <description>some info</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.version>3.13.1</azure.version>
        <azure-identity.version>1.5.0</azure-identity.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets.version>4.0.0</spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets.version>
        <jackson.version>2.12.1</jackson.version>
        <azure-core-serializer-json-jackson.version>1.2.15</azure-core-serializer-json-jackson.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-serializer-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-core-serializer-json-jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-identity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
                    <subscriptionId>xxx</subscriptionId>
                    <resourceGroup>xxxx</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>xxx</appName>
                    <pricingTier>P1v2</pricingTier>
                    <region>West Europe</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>java 11</javaVersion>
                        <webContainer>Java SE</webContainer>
                    </runtime>
                    <!-- start of APP_SETTINGS -->
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                            <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                    <!-- end of APP_SETTINGS -->
                    <deployment>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

These are the error messages:

```
[INFO] Validation error:

[ERROR] org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200
[ERROR] Maven server structure problem

[ERROR] org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200
Cannot resolve org.jboss:jandex:2.4.2.Final
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.6.6
Cannot resolve com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:1.1.0
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-orm:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.6.2
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter:3.13.0
Cannot resolve org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
Cannot resolve org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3
Cannot resolve org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:4.3.6
Cannot resolve org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-core-amqp:2.4.1
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0
Cannot resolve net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0
Cannot resolve org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.36
Cannot resolve com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
Cannot resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.6.6
Cannot resolve com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.2
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.6.2
Cannot resolve org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.0.0
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.18
Cannot resolve com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:1.11.0
Cannot resolve javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-autoconfigure:4.0.0
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.8.2
Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.6.3
Cannot resolve org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.3.Final
Cannot resolve com.h2database:h2:1.4.200
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml:classmate:1.5.1
Cannot resolve org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2
Cannot resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.11
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.18
Cannot resolve net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.11.22
Cannot resolve org.objenesis:objenesis:3.2
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.6.2
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-codec-http2:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:9.4.1.jre8
Cannot resolve io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.0.17
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.51.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:5.6.2
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot:3.13.0
Cannot resolve org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.18
Cannot resolve jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2
Cannot resolve com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:9.7
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.6.6
Cannot resolve com.nimbusds:content-type:2.1
Cannot resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.6
Cannot resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.18
Cannot resolve com.zaxxer:HikariCP:4.0.3
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-core:4.0.0
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.2
Cannot resolve io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.4.16
Cannot resolve jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.60
Cannot resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1
Cannot resolve jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.2
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:2.2.3
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.18
Cannot resolve net.minidev:accessors-smart:2.4.8
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.2.7
Cannot resolve org.apache.qpid:proton-j:0.33.8
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:1.11.9
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-common:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.6
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.2
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-core:1.24.1
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-service:4.0.0
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-core-management:1.5.3
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets:4.0.0
Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.7.Final
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.6.2
Cannot resolve net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.5.0
Cannot resolve org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.8.4
Cannot resolve com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0-1
Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.60
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2
Cannot resolve org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.8.2
Cannot resolve net.minidev:json-smart:2.4.8
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-codec-socks:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:1.0.17
Cannot resolve antlr:antlr:2.7.7
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:1.3.3
Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.6.3
Cannot resolve org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
Cannot resolve org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2.2
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.6.2
Cannot resolve org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.29
Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.60
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.1
Cannot resolve com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.14
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.6.6
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-core-serializer-json-jackson:1.2.15
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:2.0.51.Final
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.13.2
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve com.nimbusds:lang-tag:1.5
Cannot resolve com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.12
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.6
Cannot resolve org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.2.3.Final
Cannot resolve org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.2.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.6.6
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.2
Cannot resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
Cannot resolve com.microsoft.azure:qpid-proton-j-extensions:1.2.4
Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.13.2
Cannot resolve net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.11.22
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.6.6
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-codec-dns:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.18
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.6.6
Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:5.6.2
Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.75.Final
Cannot resolve com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.6.0
Cannot resolve com.azure:azure-identity:1.5.0
Cannot resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1
Cannot resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
Cannot resolve com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter:4.0.0
```

I tried to add the dependency under  but then I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
```

See this for reference, saying I can't add under dependencymanagement:
[Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver in spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230137/cannot-load-driver-class-org-h2-driver-in-spring-boot-application)

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could conclude that it is my firewall that most likely is the reason behind the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the version of H2 in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

you may have error in the test file, just open it and press ( Ctrl + Shift + O) to edit the import

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding the version number and different scopes. But nothing seem to work. I think it is my firewall blocking connections.

Comment: Maybe your firewall is the problem, if you solved it, just let me know that.

Comment: Yes 100% my firewall, it is rather annoying because it creates new errors every week. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should type it like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

this should work for you,
if it doesn't work, you could add the h2 version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was my firewall that caused issues and I have to run specific java version in separate command prompt to resolve.